# Youtube API 3 get latest videos - but I want the URL to just open and PLAY that video

Tags: url, redirect, youtube, youtube-api

So, I have read numerous sites and a bunch of code that can find "the newest video" uploaded or Published, but NONE of them show how to format a URL LINK to just open THAT most recent video in a new tab/window and PLAY it.
I am missing something, obviously, and would love direction and help.
Here is the code that locates the correct video listing...
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=Myin&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video&key=MyinAlso

And it literally shows up in a new tab, but just white code on a black background - NO VIDEO.

I would love this URL to just open and play that Newest uploaded/streamed video.

I have tried appending "watch?v=" with such items as "playnext=1&index=1", "videos.xml?channel_id=Myin&orderedby=published&playnext=1&index=1" and many other variations of these and other switches/directories/commands - all as links only.
By channel, playlist {when correct one is chosen} works using some variation - but - the newest Live uploaded video only exists in a non-existent list under "/streams", named or "filtered" as "Recently Uploaded" on the "LIVE" tab, or also in another non-existent List/category on the "Home" tab, named "Past Live Streams".

I just want a link that I never have to change, to play the Most Recently Uploaded Live video. This should NOT be this hard and frustrating.

Comment: `And it literally shows up in a new tab, but just white code on a black background` = add the URL of the result. What programming language you're using for this task?

Comment: Provide a channel you're using to get this data.

Comment: This solution should work with ANY Youtube site, but our Church site is "Restoration Church Homestead" ... channel/UCbhMYK2QQXgHjgnMN3zegRQ
And to reiterate exactly what I am desiring - a URL Link only, to open in a new tab, the Current/Newest Live/Uploaded video. That means, if it is LIVE right now, play it... or, if there is no LIVE right now - then play the newest/most recent.

Comment: Youtube should not make it so hard to do something so simple and basic.
Right now it seems that the only viable answer is to pay for the "service" of : https://ltstyt.be/ , which does exactly as I need.